# zsh: commands not working for pip, conda, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, zsh

So here is my story:
As we know macos comes with pyhton 2.7 preinstalled. Years ago, I installed python **3.7.0** and all going good. I started working with Tensorflow and during that time tensorflow wasn't compatible with **3.7.0** so switch the version to **3.6.6** somehow :). After some time i installed anaconda and it installed 3.7.3.
**At this point:**

- When i open my python IDLE shell, it runs on **3.6.6**
- anaconda Jupiter notebook shows **3.7.3.**

Then i learned to create virtual environments through terminal and i use following code to create virtual environment:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv project_env
```

And after i activate the virtual environment the python version it shows is **3.7.3.**

---

Then recently i changed the terminal shell to zsh and now everything is kind of messed up. I'm

1. Terminal can't find conda commands. How to fix that?
2. Now i can't create virtual environment through `virtualenv project_env`. It says command not found. Why? It use to create virtual environments with python **3.7.3**.
3. Now to create virtual environment i use `python3 -m venv project_env` this creates the virtual environment with python ****3.6.6****. If i use `python3.7 -m venv project_env` it creates environment with python **3.7.0**.
4. I can't find a way to create virtual environments with python **3.7.3**.

I need help with above troubles caused after installing zsh and help with accessing python versions wherever i need. How do i update python version 3.7.0 to latest or any specific version like 3.7.3. Hows python 3.8.4 to use, i mean like i had trouble importing tensorflow in python 3.7.0.

I hope you will understand my trouble and searched a lot for solutions. I'm so confused right now, couldn't even figure out the title of my problem.

Comment: _Then i learned to create virtual environments through terminal and i use following code to create virtual environment:_ With that, you likely have 4+ installations of Python, and at least 2 tools for package management and virtual environments. It's probably a good idea to reduce the number of tools and installations you have.

Comment: @HarmanThind : Did you configure your zsh startup files in a way paralleling your bash startup files (just using zsh syntax, where needed)?

Comment: @user1934428 I have not actually, just run the command that appears on bash shell before i install zsh. Are thses file to configure? .zshenv, .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin, .zlogout. How to configure them?

Comment: @HarmanThind : Rea in the `zshall` man page the chapter _INVOCATION_. It describes those files, and the conditions under which they are processed. From this you can choose in which of them to put your definitions. I can't tell you because I don't know the details how you are using your system, but once you understand the way zsh starts up, it is easy for you to make a decision.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact your shell can't find conda now, you should look at your "path" environment variable. Whenever you change from one shell to another, you need to look at and possible create or modify the files the shell uses upon startup. These files setup your environment (PATH, PYTHONPATH, etc), create aliases, etc. You may need to create the .zshrc, .zprofile, .zlogin etc files and add the same settings as your previous shell's startup files.

Example:
If you used the bash shell previously you would need to modify the .zshrc file to include your settings in the .bashrc file. Syntax may be different, so a straight copy may or may not work.

Try this as a quick temporary fix (may or may not work, depending on your current ~/.profile settings:

Create a ~/.zprofile file with this code inside:

```
emulate sh
. ~/.profile
emulate zsh
```

references:
https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Donald. I only have experience with configured **.bash_profile** file until now. The **.bashrc** seems empty. Do i have to copy .bash_profile settings to zsh startup files?

Comment: Good that your .bashrc file is empty, it makes this simpler. I don't think a straight copy is a good idea. The zsh shell is different from bash shell, many of the commands are different. If you run a bash command in a zsh shell, you may get errors. You can try to use the zsh "emulate" command as a workaround, but it would be best to either move your startup commands to .profile which is shell agnostic, or convert the commands one by one to the new shell startup files. I added a possible quick fix you can try in my answer above.